# How to show circle on map in sea for the records which don't have coordinates

Tags: javascript, maps, coordinates, amcharts

I have `amcharts map` which shows circle on it. I have few records(nearly 200) which do not have locations. These records(circle) I want to show in the `map` in Sea so that those records clearly will be visible.

I have tried, but circles are not working properly.

This is my code

```
result.forEach(element => {

if(element.loc=='NULL')
{
  element.lat=30.461829+0.102189
  element.long=152.516679+0.290019
}
});

this.mapImageSeries.data=result;
```

Starting `lat long` I have taken from here.

[image]

**My map showing all the circle at one place. How can I showing then one around other?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this using below `Javascript` code

```
result.forEach(element => {
if(element.loc=='NULL')
{     
  var r = 1000590/111300, // = 100000 meters
  y0 = 27.990741,
  x0 = 153.556045,

  u = Math.random(),
  v = Math.random(),
  w = r * Math.sqrt(u),
  t = 2.3 * Math.PI * v,
  x = w * Math.cos(t),
  y1 = w * Math.sin(t),
  x1 = x / Math.cos(y0),
  newY = y0 + y1,
  newX = x0 + x1
  element.lat=newY
  element.long=newX
}
});
```